# Using Blobstore from JUnit

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to test some code that uses the Blobstore API, but I don't really get how I am expected to get some files into the blobstore. The following is not working:

```
private BlobKey createBlob(String path) throws Exception {
    FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
    AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("foobar");
    FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, true);
    OutputStream output = Channels.newOutputStream(writeChannel);

    // copy files, guava-style
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(path);
    assertNotNull(input);
    ByteStreams.copy(input, output); 
    input.close();

    // just in case...
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    writeChannel.close();

    // U NO WORK!!!
    BlobKey blobKey = fileService.getBlobKey(file);
    assertNotNull(blobKey);
    return blobKey;
}
```

My config:

```
new LocalServiceTestHelper(
    new LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig()
        //.setNoStorage(true)
        .setBackingStoreLocation("war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated"),
    new LocalFileServiceTestConfig()
).setUp();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you testing the BlobStore functionality? That would be odd as its own developers should test that. Sounds like you want to mock the BlobStore object and assert and test against this

Comment: Nope. I just wanted to test my code, but I need some files in the Blobstore to do that. This is just part of my test setup.

Comment: In what sense does your code not work? Even better, post a simple repro case that others can run. For example, it would be better to see where the LocalServiceTestHelper is actually instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following test run successfully

```
public class TestBlobstore {
  private static final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = 
    new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig(),
                               new LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig()
                              );

  public TestBlobstore() {
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
  }

  @Test
  public void testBlobstore() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(createBlob("test.txt"));
  }

  private BlobKey createBlob(String path) throws Exception {
    FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
    AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("foobar");
    FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, true);
    OutputStream output = Channels.newOutputStream(writeChannel);

    // copy files, guava-style
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(path);
    assertNotNull(input);
    ByteStreams.copy(input, output); 
    input.close();

    // just in case...
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    writeChannel.closeFinally();

    // U NO WORK!!!
    BlobKey blobKey = fileService.getBlobKey(file);
    assertNotNull(blobKey);
    return blobKey;
  }
}
```

Two modifications:

- User LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig instead of LocalFileServiceTestConfig
- writeChannel.closeFinally(); instead of writeChannel.close()

Hope this help.

Comment: This test returns "com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'file' or call 'Create()' was not found." for me. Any ideas what's wrong or what i am missing?

Comment: Nevermind, using the instructions from http://svenbuschbeck.net/wordpress/2012/05/junit-testing-and-gae-apis/  under 'API pack­age not found' did the trick.

Comment: This doesn't work any more with App Engine 1.9.28. Anybody has another way?