# GAE+JUnit: Add a blob to the blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, automated-tests, blobstore

I'm using Google App Engine for Java, and I'm trying to write JUnit tests for my code that deals with the blobstore. How can I put a blob in the blobstore to use during testing (after it has been configured to keep everything in-memory with the [LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig))? It seems like the solution should be very simple and basic, but somehow I cannot find it.

I imagine it was possible using the Files API, but I have steered clear of it because it is being discontinued (next week).

The only way I know of to get blobs into the blobstore *outside* of tests is via a multi-part form upload. However, I don't know how I would do that in the context of a JUnit test.

One can also interact with Google Cloud Storage objects via the blobstore API, but I have chosen to use the vanilla blobstore so that I don't need to loop yet another service (and its client libraries) into my app.

So again I ask, how do I get a blob in there so I can test the code that uses it?

Comment: What do you mean by "in memory" blobstore service?

Comment: @jirungaray Sorry that was a misleading description.  I meant the blobstore after it has been configured with the default [LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig).  I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Have you tried this?

[Using Blobstore from JUnit][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12381385/1467894

Comment: @yesterdaysfoe Thank you for looking into it.  However, that answer uses the deprecated [Files API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/files_api_migration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you're correct that this feature does not exist. You should open a Feature Request issue in the [public issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-appengine/issues/list) and any other users interested in this can star the issue. Once that's done, it will be triaged and logged Google-side for implementation over time.

Comment: I created this feature request. If anyone else cares to star it, it is at: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12232